# How to separate gwt modules using <script> tag, and still use dev mod

Tags: gwt, module, compilation

I'm rewriting my question to be more detailed and more clear.

i have a project like this:

com.mycompany.modulue1
------------------------------------>client
------------------------------------>server
------------------------------------>shared
------------------------------------>module1.gwt.xml
com.mycompany.modulue1
------------------------------------>client (JSNI - create a method to access methods in module2)
------------------------------------>server
------------------------------------>shared
------------------------------------>module2.gwt.xml (using add-linker name="xsiframe")

in module1.html i added the following script: 
"script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="module2/Module2.nocache.js"
"script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="module1/Module1.nocache.js"

1. now i get "module2" need to be recompiled every time (even if the env. is clean and recently built
2. the JS method that is defined in module 2 is not defined when the server is up.
3. i'm using external server in dev mode (for EJB use)

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you
Ahmad Igbaria

Comment: In another simple words. i have two modules, i want to able to call methods from module A in module B without using "inherit" in moduleA.gwt.xml, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I fully understand your problem but judging by the title:

If you have a page that loads 2 distinct GWT applications, you can run only one of them in DevMode by subtituting `gwt.codesvr` in your URL with `gwt.codesvr.moduleName`, where `moduleName` is the name of the module to run in DevMode. That way, the other module won't switch to DevMode and will thus run in production mode.
This however only works with the `xsiframe` linker (for the one module you want to run in Dev Mode at least)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do want to run only one module, but the dev mode asks me for the 2nd module inheritance !!

Comment: I tried to do what you said, it didn't work! if I add the module name it doesn't start the dev mode, it runs on production mode, and if start it normally gwt.codesvr it fail loading the second module! please your help !

Comment: Do you have a `rename-to` in your module? That's the value you're supposed to use. Also, which GWT version are you using?

Comment: yes I'm using the value in the rename-to, I'm using the latest version 2.5

Comment: and I'm using <add-linker name="xsiframe" /> in the 2nd module

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot that the `gwt.codesvr.moduleName` syntax only works with the `xsiframe` linker. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After so much time and headaches, I have found the solution it's very simple, you need to add the linker to both modules not only the one you want to use as a pre-compiled!

Comment: You don't need it for both, only the one you want to run in Dev Mode.